# Django - loop over this nested structure in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my data structure.

```
var = {'a': [{'a_description': 'Some description...'}],
       'b': {'First Last': [{'some data': 'data'}]}}
```

I think we have a dictionary named var, of two dictionaries (a and b),
 where the first element of dictionary a is a list, and within that list is another dictionary. 
 and the second element b, 
 is a dictionary that holds a list, of another dictionary.

I am trying to figure out how to loop over this in a template, but am not able to conjure up the correct loops.

Comment: This really depends on what kind of output you expect to get. But it seems to me (just based on your description) that you probably want to handle `var['a']` and `var['b']` separately in your template.

Comment: Yes. that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your template:

```
{% for my_dict in var.a %}
    {# my_dict now holds the value of var['a'] #}
{% endfor %}

{% for key, my_list in var.b.items %}
    {# key is the key from var['b'], and my_list is the value associated with it #}
    {% for my_dict in my_list %}
        {# Now, my_dict is one dict from the list in var['b'][key]. #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```